# Select node where text equals text of another node

Tags: xml, xpath

Trying to select the `//site/name` from the below XML, where the `//site/homepage` is the same as `//result/url`. The immediately following XPath works for a hard-coded `//site/homepage`, but I'd like to use a selector for the equality check if possible.

```
//site[homepage/text() = "google.com"]/name/text()
```

The XML I'm trying to match.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root> 
  <site> 
    <homepage>google.com</homepage>  
    <name>Google</name>  
  </site>  
  <site> 
    <homepage>www.bing.com</homepage>  
    <name>Bing</name>  
  </site>  
  <result> 
    <name>First Result</name>  
    <url>google.com</url>  
  </result>  
  <result> 
    <name>Second Result</name>  
    <url>www.bing.com</url>  
  </result> 
</root>
```

Comment: Please list the *exact* XML nodes you wish to be selected from your example XML.  Do this as a list of result XML nodes, not as ambiguous, partial XPath expressions.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You said

> Trying to select the //site/name from the below XML, where the
>   //site/homepage is the same as //result/url

let's translate it relatively

Select the **name** that are child of **site**, for which **homepage** equals an **url** that is in any **result** element

```
//site[homepage = //result/url]/site
```